# Is every countably compact subset of a Hausdorff space closed?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is known that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. So, I have a question: Is every countably compact subset of a Hausdorff space closed?

Comment: Note that a counterexample (The countably compact set) can't be Lindelof. It seems painful.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper Yes, you are right. If space is countably compact and Lindelof then it is compact

Comment: Let $X$ be any countably compact Tychonoff space which is not compact; then $X$ has a Hausdorff compactification, in which it is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

The ordinal space $\omega_1+1$ (the set of all ordinals $\le\omega_1$ with the order topology) is a compact Hausdorff space. The subspace $\omega_1$ of all countable ordinals is countably compact but not closed.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace $\Sigma = \{f \in [0,1]^\mathbb{R}: \left|\{x: f(x) \neq 0\}\right| \le \aleph_0 \}$ of the compact space $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is countably and sequentially compact but not closed.